# Maven How to show warnings of codes when compiling

Tags: java, maven

I'm using maven to build a new project. There are some warnings in my codes which are underlined by yellow line. I wish maven could report these warnings in console. How can I accomplish that? Can I just add some parameters in the command such as  mvn -XXX clean compile?

Comment: Please show your warnings

Comment: agree with @KrishnanunniPV

Comment: Are you using a Linux or windows?

Comment: I'm using a windows.  The warnings are just like "The value of the local variable a is not used", I know how to avoid these warnings, however, I just wanna print the warning on the console.

Answer (score 13):

> **`<showDeprecation>`**
>   Sets whether to show source locations where deprecated APIs are used.
>
> - Default value is: `false`
> - User property is: `maven.compiler.showDeprecation`
>
> **`<showWarnings>`**
>   Set to `true` to show compilation warnings.
>
> - Default value is: `false`
> - User property is: `maven.compiler.showWarnings`
>
> -- [Maven Doku](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html)

As simple as `mvn clean install -Dmaven.compiler.showDeprecation=true -Dmaven.compiler.showWarnings=true` all in one line.

You could even remove the `=true` part because, when you add a maven parameter with `-D` it automatically sets its value to `true`, if not set to something else.

Comment: In my Eclipse I see about 1000+ warnings. But this shows none of them. You also need the `-Xlint:all` as shown in [answer by Glen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51842574/3124333).

Answer (score 6):

With maven 3.3.9, using the maven-compiler-plugin and Java 1.8, you need a `<configuration>` section like the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I got this answer from here when none of the above worked for me: http://frequal.com/java/EnableWarningsInMaven.html

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using the compiler plugin. Have you tried the tag ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the maven compiler plugin in your pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get to see detailed logs in maven you can use the command line option

> **-X**, **--debug**     Produce execution debug output

e.g this can be used as

```
mvn clean install -X
```

Also if what you want to get in the logs is the compiler warnings (*The value of the local variable a is not used*). You can try modifying your project's `pom.xml` with the following -

```
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <source>1.8</source>
               <target>1.8</target>
               <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            </configuration>
       </plugin>
       ... other plugins
    </plugins>
</build>
```